# Does the phrase that one "keeps their head down" have a negative connotation

Tags: word-choice, connotation

Does the phrase that one "keeps their head down" have a negative or derogatory connotation in regards to the person whose head is kept down?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: No, I don't think it does. (Native speaker here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the phrase is derived from war, in particular, trench warfare where *keeping their heads down* meant that they were less likely to be shot.

The term can be neutral:

*In the battle of rebuke between the cranky moderators, the average users kept their heads down.*

It can be critical, suggesting cowardice:

*When the CEO scanned the room seeking a solution, even the senior managers kept their heads down.*

It might reflect smarts:

*As the public panicked at the escape of the animals, the game wardens kept their heads down and waited for an opportunity to recapture.*

It is contextual, but I think it tends to be used negatively, less so neutrally, rarely positively.

Comment: Very eloquently explained.